# Getting "multiple definition of func_name" when trying to compile main with google tests

Tags: c++, googletest

I have a simple .cpp file that looks like this:

```
void showMenu()
{
    std::cout << "Hi!";
}

int main()
{
    showMenu();
    return 0;
}
```

In addition, I have an empty google-test that looks like this:

```
TEST(Name, SubName)
{

}
```

When I try to compile, I get:

```
multiple definition of `showMenu()'
```

and:

```
multiple definition of `main()'
```

errors.
How do I set my configurations so that I would be able to run my main when I went to, and my google-test when I want to, without them clashing into each other?

Answer (score 1):

The googletest library already contains a definition for `main()`.

To solve that, separate your definitions for `showMenu()` out into another library, and link that one to your testrunner and productive executable separately.

And don't `#include` your `.cpp` file with the test code.